# C# Компиляция в машинный код с помощью NET Native

Tags: c#, .net, .net-native

Недавно узнал про возможность скомпилировать код C# в машинный код с помощью NET Native. В чем подвох? Это работает только под Windows10/UWP или можно с любым проектом? Команды для компиляции предлагаемые в интернете не работают, в NET вообще не нашел команды compile.

Есть ли реальная возможность перевести код C# в машинный? (Например проект WPF)

Comment: .NET Native != .NET - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/, а зачем это вам вообще?

Comment: Если вас не устраивает скорость работы .net, вас никто не заставляет писать на нем. Хотите скорости? Используйте с, с++ и другие низкоуровневые языки.

Comment: У Mono вроде была такая фишка, но без WPF.

Comment: Спасибо всем, оказывается, пока что эта технология работает только по UWP

Comment: Странно, у меня вот работает с консольным приложением: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ready-to-run. ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: @こきん: Скорость не обязательно требует нативного приложения. Может, вам будет интересно почитать: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-chineseenglish-dictionary-reader